# php double overflow problem

Tags: php, post, casting, floating-point, double

I'm sure this is quite simple but I can't find the answer.

I'm passing a double into a PHP page, and retrieving it with the code:

```
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
```

The number being passed (1291328282) gets changed into -1456872199 by the PHP script.  The code:

```
$timestamp = (float) $_POST['timestamp'];
```

has the same result.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['timestamp'])` give? It should be a string.

Comment: i can bet its a string of an unix timestamp.

Comment: fyi, I'm passing in the value obtained from java:  double timestamp = (double) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);

Comment: @RobertPitt, That number and UNIX timestamps in general fit in signed 32-bit integers, so there's no reason for the above code to be some negative number. Either a negative number is directly being passed to PHP or other code is manually messing up the `$_POST`.

Comment: Yea i know, thats why i requested in my reply to see the form, to see if he is doing `<input type="hidden" value="-1291328282" />`

Comment: gahhh You're right, I was making a mistake before it got to the PHP page.  Sorry all

Comment: AHHH, jave, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in PHP. 'float', 'double' or 'real' are the same datatype.

`$_POST['timestamp'];` if has the value of `1291328282` is not a double, but an `int`, it looks like a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` not to get confused with EPOCH.

Im not sure what you wish to achive but i think you want:

```
$timestamp = (int)$_POST['timestamp'];
```

---

Little extra knowledge:

When converting from float to string trailing zeros will be dropped.

Example (5.3.^)

```
echo (string)5.00500; // outputs 5.005
echo (string)30.0000; // outputs 30
```

What you want to do is:

```
$timestamp = abs((int)$_POST['timestamp']);
```

Comment: I tried that, with the same results as before...still giving me a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling the data after declaring the variable?  Everything submitted through a form is a string. PHP puts the data into $_POST as strings (except for arrays).  $timestamp should have the correct value *upon declaration* because strings are not constrained like an integer is.  What you do with $timestamp *after* declaring it is what's likely causing PHP to clunk out.

Comment: I'm just writing the value to a file after POSTing it